# Division by Zero Error in a Simple Program

Tags: c++, error-handling, divide-by-zero

For whatever reason a simple test program is generating division by zero errors even though division by zero is impossible as far as I can tell:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int Level = 1;
    int EXPTNL = 0;

    cout << Level << endl;

    EXPTNL = (Level * 1250) * 1000 * 1000 * Level / (2 / ((1000 * (Level * 1250)) / 2));

    cout << EXPTNL << endl;

    system("Pause");
}
```

Am I missing something?  This exact same formula works just fine in another, much more complex, program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will almost certainly lead to a zero value:

```
(2 / ((1000 * (Level * 1250))
```

if `level` is non-zero, `1000 * (Level * 1250)`, is much larger than 2, which in integer division will give the result zero.

Maybe you want to use a floating point value so that your EXPTNL becomes a floating point calculation, and then make it an integer at the end.

I also expect (Level * 1250) * 1000 * 1000 to oveflow a 32-bit integer, so you probably want that as a floating point calculation.

Just make each of the 1250 values into a 1250.0 and problem solved.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  It helped me with this but also it exposed a major problem with my exp calculation where I was a whole decimal point off for the numerator of the simplified equation.

Answer (score 3):

This is integer division:

```
2 / ((1000 * (Level * 1250)) / 2)
```

and, since the denominator's magnitude is larger than that of the numerator, you get 0.

It would have been easy to test this:

```
std::cout << (2 / ((1000 * (Level * 1250)) / 2)) << std::endl;
```

You need floating point division, which you can get by having a floating point number in the numerator or denominator (or both).

Comment: You are right.  In the program this originates from I had EXPTNL set up as a double instead of an int, so even though the program compiled with no warning it produce erroneous data that I had not seen yet as I have not linked the main function to any of the stuff from that class for testing :o  Three birds with one stone.